# MySQL Query group by to get the last id

Tags: mysql, group-by

this is my table

```
id | sender | receiver | msg  
-----------------------------
1  | jon    | jack     | buzz ...  
2  | jack   | jon      | ?  
3  | adel   | jon      | met me soon  
4  | jon    | adel     | okay  
5  | alex   | jon      | where ar u ?  
6  | jon    | adel     | okay  
7  | adel   | alex     | don't forget the party  
8  | jon    | jack     | may i borrow ur car 
9  | alex   | adel     | of course
10 | jack   | jon      | ok
11 | jack   | jon      | watch the gas
12 | alex   | jon      | i'm dying here
13 | jon    | alex     | 5 mnt ..
```

and i want get list last messages of jon with his friend like this

```
id | sender | receiver | msg
-------------------------------------------
13 | jon    | alex     | 5 mnt ..
11 | jack   | jon      | watch the gas
6  | jon    | adel     | okay
```

How to query, to get that result ?

Comment: nb.,, i only need 3 record ..

Comment: Have you looked at my query ? :s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM table
    WHERE sender = 'jon' 
       OR receiver = 'jon'
    GROUP BY IF(sender = "jon", receiver, sender)
) 
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

**Edit**: Thanks for the edit ypercube, I really forgot something important here :)

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, now read again Chad's question and apologize ;-)

Comment: i'm not really understand but this is what i need, just add 'ORDER BY id DESC' for sort. Thank you..

Comment: I guess you don't know how grateful I am for this solution. I have been looking for this for days!!

Answer (score 3):

This returns exactly what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE sender="jon" OR receiver="jon" ORDER BY id DESC) a 
GROUP BY IF(sender = "jon", receiver, sender) 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Sorry for wrong answer first time, I guess I didn't read the question carefully. :(

Here's the test:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e66ac/2

Comment: Chad wants to get the last message of jon with `each` of his friends.

Comment: have you try it ?, this query return 11 rows, then what i need is 3 row. not the jon message with other but every 'last' jon messege with other, he had 3 friend so result is 3 .

Comment: You're welcome, I just added the wrapper around my initial answer to group by jon's friend.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM tblA WHERE sender="jon" OR receiver="jon" ORDER BY id DESC) a 
GROUP BY IF(sender = "jon", receiver, sender)
```

Please refer to http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44099/1

Answer (score 1):

Try this::

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE sender ='jon' OR receiver='jon' 
GROUP BY msg 
ORDER BY id desc
```

Comment: +1 but he has written here 3 record doesn't mean that he also want only 3 record

Comment: @Random: thanks but I looked that there were 4 messages and only 3 are being displayed, so i have grouped by msg..

Comment: Chad wants to get the last message of jon with `each` of his friends.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE sender="jon" OR receiver="jon" ORDER BY id DESC`

Answer (score -1):

**This is simple query you can change according to your logic**

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_enquiry WHERE id IN (
  SELECT Max(id) FROM tbl_enquiry WHERE date = '06/25/2015' GROUP BY cust_id 
) LIMIT 0 , 30
```